# How to deploy Angular 7 Universal application to IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, angular7, universal, iisnode

I already working on an angular 7 project we just use ng build --prod to create a production build and just copy the content of the dist folder to IIS folder and it works fine. Now I have make this application universal using @ng-toolkit/universal its working fine on my local machine now I have to deploy this application to IIS server. So what we need to copy to IIS folder as now we have two sub folders inside dist folder one for "browser" and one for "Server" and server.js file in the dist folder. m confused which content should I copy to IIS folder and make it work. I have deployed the whole dist folder but it doesn't seem to work. I have created the production build using the following command. 
"npm run build:prod"

Comment: Hello I am also facing the same confusion.
Did you got any solution for the same?

Comment: Hello @KunalKakkad, run this command on cli "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr". After successfully run it'll show you the message server is listening on the specified port. Than open your dist folder and copy two folders from there "browser","server" and server.js file and paste those to IIS folder. Open your cmd in administrative mode and change its path to that IIS folder and run the command. "npm install express". after the successful installation you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for it. Will give it try for the same. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: hello, after copying and installation if i run the hosted site on iis I am not even getting the index page. Can you please let me know what I am missing for the same?

Comment: @KunalKakkad you need to install URL Rewrite extension for IIS. Here is the link https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I have installed the same and now need to add any kind of rule or something?

Comment: @KunalKakkad Download the config file from below link and place it in your IIS folder where you have pasted your browser and server folder                https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cA8XrfRCt3tK2hKsncAgb6hgZ03PArLS

Comment: I am getting following error when i replaced the web.config:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: @MohammadNaeem am stuck with final config file.. Can u please guide me... If i replace with your config file. its showing 404 found error..

Comment: @KunalKakkad have you added the another web.config file in your "src" folder for client application. if not than please add that to "src" folder and in your angular.json file add the path to that "web.config" file in the assets array. like "src/web.config". you can download that config file from below link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-O5KkLyRWZo6QcnDcRIY10bh2HbiU_F

Comment: still 500 error. Something is missing. Error says iisnode